# How to determine who last changed a file with JGit

Tags: java, jgit

There is [a good cook-book receipt](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/ShowBlame.java) for JGit which describes how to blame the author of a specific line in a file.

Now I want to know who last changed a file. Iterating over all lines to find the last changed line looks a little bit not so elegant. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `LogCommand` with a path filter like this:

```java
Iterable<RevCommit> iterable = git.log().addPath( "foo.txt" ).call();
RevCommit latestCommit = iterable.iterator().next();
```

The code looks for the `latestCommit` that modified `foo.txt`. I haven't tested the above snippet with merge commits or other commits that have more than one parent.

**Note** however that this solution potentially may leak resources: the `RevWalk` which provides the iterator is created by the `LogCommand` but never closed.

In order to avoid the resource leak you can manually iterate the history like so:

```
RevCommit latestCommit = null;
String path = "file.txt";
try( RevWalk revWalk = new RevWalk( git.getRepository() ) ) {
  Ref headRef = git.getRepository().exactRef( Constants.HEAD );
  RevCommit headCommit = revWalk.parseCommit( headRef.getObjectId() );
  revWalk.markStart( headCommit );
  revWalk.sort( RevSort.COMMIT_TIME_DESC );
  revWalk.setTreeFilter( AndTreeFilter.create( PathFilter.create( path ), TreeFilter.ANY_DIFF ) );
  latestCommit = revWalk.next();
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't something like `git.log().addPath("README.md").call()` work?

Comment: Because the `LogCommand` does not offer a `setPath()` method. But thanks for your dissent, I think the above snippet could be simplified with a `TreeFilter`. I will update the post soon.

Comment: Thanks to @centic the snippet abive is now much simpler.

Comment: Hi @RüdigerHerrmann you are nearly right. LogComand does have a '''addPath''' which works similar to '''addPath'''. I have a working solution with LogComand. It's a bit special that a Git object needs to be created as described here: https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/ShowLog.java . If you want you could describe it than I would accept it otherwise I write it on my own. So centics solution worked for me.

Comment: Sorry, I was confusing `addPath` with `setPath`. Thanks for your feedback.